# run useState on unmounted component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a state which is used to render some components conditionally, I have the following structure:

```js
const SearchScreen = () => {
  const [isSearchBarFocused, setIsSearchBarFocused] = React.useState(false);

  return (
      <>
         <SearchBar onFocus={setIsSearchBarFocused} />
         {isSearchBarFocuse ? <SearchSuggestionList isSearchBarFocused={isSearchBarFocused} setIsSearchBarFocused={setIsSearchBarFocused} /> : null}
      </>
  )

}
```

As you can see in the code above, the state seter is shared by both components, when the `<SearchBar />` is focused the state changes to `true` and when an option is selected from the `<SearchSuggestionList />` the state change to `false`. The problem with this approach is that I need to run some API calls and other inner state updates in `<SearchSuggestionList />` component but this is unmounted due to the conditional rendering then some processes are not reached to be carried out.

then how would I execute code that is inside a component that can be unmounted?

Comment: I would suggest that you use `style={{display: 'none'}}` for hiding `<SearchSuggestionList />` instead of conditional rendering.

Comment: Agreed, but that applies for this specific case, I would like to know if there is any other option for other use case when  I couldn’t just hide the component

Comment: so, basically when it remounts, again the useEffects gets called right for SearchSuggestionList

Comment: Yes but what I need is that the code associated with the component is executed before unmount, I know that in a new render the component is mounted but if it is unmounted again the code is not reachable and would not be executed.

Comment: What you want to achieve and with the approach you are describing is not possible, not that I know. This sounds more like a design/structural issue. Can you include what `SearchSuggestionList` is supossed to do so we can have a better understanding of the logic? Maybe the solution would be to lift some states up and re-consider the overall structure of the search screen.

Answer (score 1):

At `SearchScreen`component:  You need to add event `onBlur` for `search-input`, it will auto trigger when click outside `search-input`. And add two events `onChange` and `value` to get the enter value from `search-input`. Finally, don't check `isSearchBarFocused` variable outside `SearchSuggestionList` component.

```
export default function SearchScreen() {
  const [isSearchBarFocused, setIsSearchBarFocused] = useState(false);
  const [searchBarValue, setSearchBarValue] = useState("");

  const handleChangeSearchValue = (e) => {
    setSearchBarValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleBlurSearch = () => {
    setIsSearchBarFocused(false);
  };

  const handleFocusSearch = () => {
    setIsSearchBarFocused(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="searchbar-wrapper">
        <input
          className="search-input"
          type="text"
          onFocus={handleFocusSearch}
          onChange={handleChangeSearchValue}
          value={searchBarValue}
          onBlur={handleBlurSearch}
        />
        <SearchSuggestionList
          isSearchBarFocused={isSearchBarFocused}
          searchBarValue={searchBarValue}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

At `SearchSuggestionList` component: You need to create `isSearchBarFocused` and `searchBarValue` for `Props`. The `display` atrribute will change `none or block` depend on `isSearchBarFocused`

```
.search-list {
  display: none;
}

.search-list.active {
  display: block;
}
```

and if `searchBarValue` changes value, `useEffect` will trigger and re-call API

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const MOCKUP_DATA = [
  { id: 1, value: "Clothes" },
  { id: 2, value: "Dress" },
  { id: 3, value: "T-shirt" }
];

const SearchSuggestionList = ({ searchBarValue, isSearchBarFocused }) => {
  const [suggestionData, setSuggestionData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    // useEffect will call API first time and re-call every time `searchBarValue` changed value.
    console.log("re-call api");
    setSuggestionData(MOCKUP_DATA);
  }, [searchBarValue]);

  const handleClick = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
  };

  return (
    <ul className={`search-list ${isSearchBarFocused ? "active" : ""}`}>
      {suggestionData.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id} onMouseDown={() => handleClick(item.value)}>
          {item.value}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default SearchSuggestionList;
```

**Warning:** If you use `onClick` to replace `onMouseDown`, it will not work. Because `onBlur` event of `search-input` will trigger before `onClick` event  of the items in `SearchSuggestionList`

---

You can demo it at this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-cori-m1bsv0?file=/src/App.jsx

Comment: I need to hide the suggestionList component when a sugestión list item in pressed, not only when the search bar is focused/blurred

Comment: Did you check that function in Demo? `SearchSuggestionList` will hide when you pressed  a `SuggestionItem`

Comment: In Demo, `SearchSuggestionList` only hide by `CSS` not have to Unmounted component.